# Conditionally add remove <script>, <link> nodes from <head>

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a web project which dynamically loads many javascript code. This code needs additional includes (links to external js and css files in head). These includes are needed only at the beginning of user experiance on my site. Some kind of configuration. Therefore currently I included - hard coded in the main page's head node - all needed script and link nodes.

So, do I get any benefits if I maintain only currently needed script link in header (yes, I preferre they appear in header, not in body)?
Does these nodes add additional load on my page loading?

And, second question, how can I conditionaly add remove script link nodes in order to support only those of them which are really needed at the given moment during the page lifetime?

... and a last question how do you think about grouping script link node inside a div (within a head)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will slow your page down by having having many includes. These are additional calls to the server that could be avoided. You could configure you header section so that it is included on every page but has conditions written in so that only the includes required are loaded using conditional if statements.